Why does adding a constraint in ompr using a variable not work as expected?
I have a problem with the ompr (latest version 1.0.4) package in R. I want to add a constraint to a MILPModel object with a variable. It works when I provide the function with the literal string, it does not however when using the variable.
The following code reproduces my problem:
library(dplyr, quietly = TRUE)
library(ompr)

max_vector <- c(3,3,3)


# 1. Literal string -> works

mdl <- MILPModel() %>% 
    add_variable("var1"[t], t = 1:3) %>% 
    add_variable("var2"[t], t = 1:3) %>% 
    add_constraint(.constraint_expr = "var1[t] + var2[t] == max_vector[t]", t = 1:3)


# 2. With variable -> Does not work

expr_string <- "var1[t] + var2[t] == max_vector[t]"

mdl <- MILPModel() %>% 
    add_variable("var1"[t], t = 1:3) %>% 
    add_variable("var2"[t], t = 1:3) %>% 
    add_constraint(.constraint_expr = expr_string, t = 1:3)

#1 works , but #2 does not. It produces: "Error: constraint not well formed. Must be a linear (in)equality." . I tried to use {{ }} and !! operators on expr_string which don't work either.
I tried to understand what is going on and I checked the GitHub repo. Apparently, the function add_constraint_.milp_model is called, since it is the only that produces this error message. It is rather straight forward what happens with the .constraint_expr parameter.
In the function add_constraint_.milp_model in R/milp-impl.R file the following happens to the parameter:
add_constraint_.milp_model <- function(.model,
                                       .constraint_expr,
                                       ...,
                                       .dots,
                                       .show_progress_bar = TRUE) {

# ... some other code not affecting `constraint_expr`

  constraint_expr <- lazyeval::as.lazy(.constraint_expr)

# ... some other code not affecting `constraint_expr`

  constraint_ast <- constraint_expr$expr

  if (length(constraint_ast) != 3) {
    stop("constraint not well formed. Must be a linear (in)equality.",
      call. = FALSE
    )

# ... the rest of the function

Here I reproduce what happens:
expr_string <- "var1[t] + var2[t] == max_vector[t]"

.constraint_expr <- expr_string
constraint_expr <- lazyeval::as.lazy(.constraint_expr)
constraint_ast <- constraint_expr$expr

length(constraint_ast) # -> returns 3

This exactly reproduces what happens in the function to the parameter .constraint_expr . However, the length of constraint_ast  is equal to 3. So if this is really what is happening in the function, the error message should not should up.
I'm confused, does anybody understand what is going on and knows a way how to use the function milp::add_constraint()  in a way that passes the .constraint_expr  as variable, not as literal string (or formula)?
